# Get a total from symmetric intigers from array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, function, sorting, reverse

ok so i have array for example $arr= "/43sdsd555ksldk66sd"544fdfd";

I take numbers using `preg_match_all '/\d+/'`, and `array_map('intval', $zni[0]);`

Now the problem is i need to reverse those whole int to see if they are symmetric,like 555 and 66 , and if they are GET A TOTAL OF THEM.(total of only symmetric numbers)

i tried to use function " strrev "and got symmetric numbers, but i don't know how to put them in a one place IF THEY ARE symmetric and calculate them.

```
<?php
$numbers = "";

if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $numbers = ($_GET['niz']);
    preg_match_all('/\d+/', $numbers, $zni);
    $numtwo= array_map('intval', $zni[0]);
}

foreach ($numtwo as $num)
{
    $reverse = strrev($num);
    var_dump($reverse);

    if ($num == $reverse)
    {
        $reverse = "true";
    } else {
        $reverse = "false";
    }
    var_dump($reverse);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like homework?

Comment: You already have most of it. Initialize a variable to zero, and any time you set `$reverse = "true"`, add the current number to that variable as well.

Comment: I don't see why the intval step is needed, though. You're just changing it back into a string to do the reverse comparison anyway.

Comment: to see if num are symmetric .... i just need to get separate variables if they are symmetric , so i can calculate them. but idk how to do it in code...i have it in my head :^ ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already got most of the way there and all you were missing basically was to use `+` or `+=`, here is an easy example on how to do it:

```
$input = "/43sdsd555ksldk66sd544fdfd";
$total = 0;

preg_match_all('/\d+/', $input, $m);
foreach ($m[0] as $d)
    if ($d == strrev($d))
        $total += $d;

var_dump($total); // => int(621)
```

Using [`intval()`](https://secure.php.net/intval) is not necessary as PHP will implicitly cast between types as needed.

Alternatively you can replace the loop with PHP's `array_*` functions:

```
$input = "/43sdsd555ksldk66sd544fdfd";

preg_match_all('/\d+/', $input, $m);
$total = array_sum(array_filter($m[0], function ($v) { return $v == strrev($v); }));

var_dump($total); // => int(621)
```

Here we use an anonymous function with [`array_filter()`](https://secure.php.net/array_filter) to generate a new array that only contains palindrome numbers from the original matches which is then given to [`array_sum()`](https://secure.php.net/array_sum).

So all that's needed to transform your original code into a working example, is introducing a variable and summing up:

```
<?php
$numbers = "";

if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $numbers = ($_GET['niz']);
    preg_match_all('/\d+/', $numbers, $zni);
    $numtwo= array_map('intval', $zni[0]);
}

$total = 0; // new variable
foreach ($numtwo as $num)
{
    $reverse = strrev($num);
    var_dump($reverse);

    if ($num == $reverse)
    {
        $reverse = "true";
        $total += $num; // sum up
    } else {
        $reverse = "false";
    }
    var_dump($reverse);
}

var_dump($total); // => int(621)
```